# I want to get the names of my spinboxes in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qspinbox

How can I pull the names of my spinBoxes? I tried looking at a lot of the documentation, however, I couldn't find anything that would show the names of each of the child spinBoxes. I've tried changing the result to a string. However, I just get a Hex or Long Int, of the address I’d imagine, returned instead.

[image]

```
QList<QSpinBox*> spinBoxes= findChildren<QSpinBox*>();
    //create the QSignalMapper object
    QSignalMapper* signalMapper= new QSignalMapper(this);
    //loop through your spinboxes list
    QSpinBox* spinBox;
    foreach(spinBox, spinBoxes){
        //setup mapping for each spin box
        connect(spinBox, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), signalMapper, SLOT(map()));
        signalMapper->setMapping(spinBox, spinBox);
    }
    //connect the unified mapped(QWidget*) signal to your spinboxWrite slot
    connect(signalMapper, SIGNAL(mapped(QWidget*)), this, SLOT(spinboxWrite(QWidget*)));
.
.
.

void GuiTest::SpinBoxChanged(QWidget* wSp){
    QSpinBox* sp= (QSpinBox*)wSp;                   //now sp is a pointer to the QSpinBox that emitted the valueChanged signal
    int value = sp->value();                        //and value is its value after the change

    //do whatever you want to do with them here. . .
    qDebug() << value << "SpinBoxChanged";
}

void GuiTest::spinboxWrite(QWidget* e){
    SpinBoxChanged(e);
    QString* value = (QString*)e;
    qDebug() << e << value << " SpinBoxWrite";

}
```

Please note **qDebug() << e** as this is where I'm having trouble getting some information about the spinboxes

Comment: Is there a reason you can't store them as member variables?

Comment: Isn't it easier to give them a name and use that to reference them?

Comment: No, because that means looking that name up somehow. `findChild`, a map, a hash etc. have a runtime cost probably a order of magnitude bigger than just remembering the pointers as member variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name you are trying to retrieve is the [`objectName`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#objectName-prop) property, which every `QObject` and `QObject`-derived class has. Call `objectName()` to retrieve this value.

You can also use this with the [`QObject::findChild()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#findChild) function.

This should get what you want:

```
void GuiTest::spinboxWrite(QWidget* e){
    SpinBoxChanged(e);
    qDebug() << e->objectName() << " SpinBoxWrite";
```

And will output:

> "norm_spinBox_10"  SpinBoxWrite

**Note**
This line is dangerous:

```
QSpinBox* sp= (QSpinBox*)wSp;
```

Use [`qobject_cast`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#qobject_cast) instead of C-style casts.

Comment: @tisaconundrum Please note my edited-in warning about C-style casts.

Comment: Also: using `qobject_cast` in combination with the [`sender`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#sender) function, you can get rid of `QSignalMapper`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to get the name of a variable as a string.

However, you can use a `QMap<QSpinBox*, QString>` to map each spin-box to its name.

In the constructor you have to assign these manually:

```
map[ui->spinBox] = "spinBox";
map[ui->spinBoxWithStrangeName] = "spinBoxWithStrangeName";
```

Then you can simply get the strings using:

```
QString name = map[ui->spinBox];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just give them names in the designer file and then use that name to retrieve them in the C++ code.

```
QSpinBox* mySpinner = findChild<QSpinBox*>("myGivenName");
```